# Unexpected retain count after calling CFMakeCollectable

Tags: objective-c, retain

I have this bit of code:

```
 CFDictionaryRef lDictionary = AACreateDictionaryForFile(path);
 if (lDictionary) {
      printf("retct before: %ld\n", CFGetRetainCount(lDictionary));
      CFMakeCollectable(lDictionary);
      printf("retct after: %ld\n", CFGetRetainCount(lDictionary));
      return TRUE;
 } else {
      return FALSE;
 }
```

Surprisingly, after the the code is run the console shows the following output:

retct before: 1
retct after: 2147483647

I would have expected:

retct before: 1
retct after: 0

Am I doing something wrong? Do I have incorrect expectations?

Comment: You are doing something wrong in a sense, though you're hardly unusual in doing so. Don't check retain counts. Don't have expectations about them. Never ever ever make decisions based on them. They're an implementation detail, not a useful piece of information.

Comment: Thanks for verifying that I (almost) know what I'm doing. I know retain counts are not very dependable, but I wasn't quite expecting these results. Anyway, I just wanted to make sure there wasn't something more obvious that I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

2147483647 is (2^31)-1: that's the maximum value for a 32 bit signed integer.

The garbage collector certainly uses this value as a kind of flag. So don't worry, your code is OK.